# Windows MikTeX can't find my .sty file

Tags: packages, miktex, package-writing

I posted a question like this earlier but I'm re-asking because I didn't ask properly before.

I created a `.sty` file (`preamble.sty`) to help clean up my preamble but I'm having trouble actually using the packages in my document.

Other questions I have followed (in order) without any luck:

-[Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex)
My file path to the `.sty` file is `C:/Users/me/texmf/TeX/LaTeX/PreambleStuff`. I used the MikTeX GUI to add it as a root in the "Settings," then made sure I clicked "Refresh FNDB"

-[Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te)
I used the `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME` command line and the command prompt window did not show any file path, just displayed a new `C:\Users\me>` prompt. Does this mean that I don't have a texmf home directory? I also used the command `kpsewhich preamble.sty` which shows the correct file path to the file (see file path above).

-https://docs.miktex.org/manual/texfeatures.html#includedirectory 
I typed`latex --include-directory=C:/Users/me/texmf/TeX/LaTeX/PreambleStuff preamble.sty` and the command window shows `! LaTeX Error: \usepackage before \documentclass.` `See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.`

The last part raises questions of whether or not I actually wrote my `.sty` file correctly, but I am mostly concerned with getting MikTeX to find the file and include it properly in each document. What else can I do or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you add your path to miktex settings and than renew database? see instruction for "console": https://miktex.org/howto/miktex-console. welcome to tex.se!

Comment: The path is wrong. The tex folder is missing. The sty  should be in texmf\tex\latex\preamblestuff.the root is then the texmf.

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to compile your `.sty` file on its own. Your main `.tex` file should say something like `\documentclass{…}` `\usepackage(preamble)` `\begin{document}` `...` `\end{document}`. To get that working, you can put `preamble.sty` in the same directory as your main `.tex` file. When that compiles successfully, *then* go back to figure out where you really want to put the `.sty` file so you can use it in other documents as well.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That is a typo. I have updated the post to correct that. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @alephzero The `.sty` file works fine when I put it in the same folder as the `main.tex` file. I'm asking where should my `.sty` file go in this case? The other instructions aren't working (unless I'm following them wrong.)

Comment: Please confirm in your question/answer that **avoiding** using consol administrator you "Registered" **C:/Users/me/texmf** per link given by @zarko and **then** renewed FNDB (via tools) **wait** till it completes then exit MiKTeX console and re-enter as basic (not admin) user to verify it stuck.

Comment: @KJO I do not have a MiKTeX console on my computer as per the visual in the link provided by Zarko. I do have a MiKTeX Settings application that has the necessary tools to register the file path and renew FNDB (both of which I have done). The file path is still listed under `Roots` on the settings console when I restart the console. The console gives me no indication or option for running as user or administrator.

Comment: Sorry **ass**umed you are using console as it so much easier, the system CLI commands are (assuming your "me" is only latin aTOz with no spaces, punctuation or accents) and **of course** miktex bin is on your system path. [1] initexmf --user-roots=C:/Users/me/texmf --update-fndb=C:/Users/me/texmf --update-fndb [2] type "c:\your path to MiKTeX app\texmfs\install\miktex\config\miktexstartup.ini" [3] check it shows correct [Paths] UserRoots=C:/Users/me/texmf

Comment: Show a screenshot how the file path is listed as root. Regarding your number of typos and missing info I want to see the path and not your recording.

Comment: Having to presume from your paths and comments your running on windows with just an installer I suggest even if your trying to keep to the minimum that the console package is only 200kB of pure gold in a situation such as this, if you have it installed without your knowledge then running c:\> miktex-console should invoke it

Comment: @KJO Can you clarify what you mean by "MiKTeX app?" I would like to have the console for this and future projects, I'm just not sure exactly how to download it correctly.

Comment: Ok my bad (loose) use of terminology.In MiKTeX the Console package is the GUI frontend which allows you to set paths. by "path to Miktex app" I mean something like "program files (x86)\miktex2.9\" it will depend on how many bits your windows is and which locale your working in.

Comment: Thus on reading your question more carefully you do have the GUI but the path you set is wrong which is why @UlrikeFischer has asked for a screenshot of the settings > directories tab

Comment: @UlrikeFischer [Photo of the MiKTeX Options console showing the file path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVGON.png)

Comment: Ok now I see your using older (depreciated) console any reason you have not updated to new console via Package Manager?. Though if it works don't fix it ?. Your path as shown seems correct. can you find and check contents of miktexstartup.ini ?

Comment: I did not know that the console that I am using is out of date. I will work on updating it soon. I followed your code for [2] (to find `miktexstartup.ini`) and Windows tells me `The system cannot find the path specified`. I searched and it appears that I do not have a `texmfs` folder in my `MiKTeX 2.9` folder. Is there another folder I should be using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your local TEXMF tree should **not** be a subfolder of MiKTeX\texmfs , although it can be a sibling tree as in the screenshot. The key is it ends texmf not texmf\tex\lat...\…

[image]

Ideally it should be in an area where you have no user control issues and a common suggestion is C:\users\yourname\mytexmf as similar to ~/mytexmf of Linux. However due to the variety of user names it is better to use something like c:\miktexdata\mytexmf avoiding spaces, punctuation or accented characters.

Once you are sure it looks ok, go to `Tasks` and `Refresh file name database`.
Exit the console and check MiKTeX is not running in the background.
Re-enter MiKTeX console and check the setting is still the same.

IF you are not running console you can do the same from the command line using

```
initexmf --user-roots=c:\mytexmf --update-fndb=c:\mytexmf --update-fndb
```

or as suggested in another thread by Ulrike Fischer

```
initexmf --register-root=c:\mytexmf
```

If your still having problems, on a portable install that setting may be stored in a single miktexstartup.ini file, check its contents and there is not a second file with that name. In a basic user install it is stored in the registry under Computer\HKCU\Software\MiKTeX.org\MiKTeX\2.9\Core. If your confident with searching you could check the entry is identical.

To test it works download a well tested additional package such as [mwe.tds.zip](http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/mwe.tds.zip) and install that (unzip the contents so included folders `doc source and tex` are included in your personal texmf as mytexmf/tex/ mytexmf/doc mytexmf/source)

**Ensure you Update file name database** either in console or via command line

Prepare a simple MWE file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth ]{example-image-a}
\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth ]{example-image-b}
\caption{MWE to demonstrate how to place to images side-by-side }
\end{figure}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

it should run and you will see a reference to C:/mytexmf\tex\latex\mwe\mwe.sty thus proving the personal texmf is set correctly for a .sty  NOTE: MiKTeX uses / for the stored absolute part to texmf and \ for the relative parts below that, this is acceptable to windows.

Comment: My first post was not as clear as I thought. My local TEXMF tree is at `C:/Users/Me/texmf` as prescribed in the first link of the original post. My MiKTeX settings application shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVGON.png) as the file path.

Comment: I have been looking to find a useful MWE test case, which I have included in my answer. It will prove if MiKTeX recognises your TEXMF/TDS as valid. Any other package that fails after that is probably **not** TDS compliant

Comment: What settings should be added or modified in the `miktexstartup.ini` file? Although I added the directory in the MikTeX console and updated the FNDB, I still can't access my custom sty files.

Comment: @Tommiie My answer was directed to the main question so would need to know what point **you** are starting from. If your case is different from the above and the answer does not work it may be best to raise a fresh question with details of this and other answers you tested, it may be flagged down as duplicate if you don't explain the steps you have attempted without success, clearly show OS, & MiKTeX versions and how installed (portable/install paths) also explain what folder locations you have tested that do or don't work since your likely be told by default to put the .sty alongside the .tex

Comment: Never mind. It seems I've hit a bug, added my own answer just as info for someone else who might hit the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

For me I hit a bug in MikTeX. To solve the issue I used the answer provided by @KJO and in addition, I manually edited the file `miktexstartup.ini` in the directory `<installdir>\texmfs\install\miktex\config`:

```
;;; MiKTeX startup information

[Auto]
Config=Portable

[Paths]
UserRoots=D:\miktex-portable\mytexmf
```

For me the `<installdir>` was `D:\miktex-portable`. After manually adding the line `UserRoots`, restarting MikTeX portable, and building the FNDB, it worked!